# HBase query when rowkey is not completely known

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am planning to store streaming weather data in HBase. My rowkey is:
[5 letter city code][timestamp] where timestamp is [date][time as in HH:mm:ss.SSS]
and I have just one column called "temperature". So sample data would look like:

```
NEWYO20131121080932123 32.4  
NEWYO20131121081034342 34.6  
NEWYO20131121081156424 31.8  
NEWYO20131121081223532 24.9  
SINGA20131121091142563 23.1  
SANFR20131121091214763 22.1
```

I want to query data to return me temperature values in New York between 8:11 and 8:13 on 21st November (rows 3 and 4 should be returned)

How do I write a query for this using the Java API.

I came across `Scan(byte[] startRow, byte[] stopRow)`, but I don't think that I can use that, since I don't know the exact rowkey while retrieving data (because of the seconds and the milliseconds at the end of the key)

(Is it possible to use regex for rowkeys?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

startkey is NEWYO20131121081100000
endkey is   NEWYO20131121081400000

BTW:
There is no need to use hbase native API.
you can check http://phoenix.incubator.apache.org/
or https://github.com/zhang-xzhi/simplehbase

Answer (score 1):

you can use RowFilter. The following code will help

```
Filter filter2 = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
new RegexStringComparator("regex"));
scan.setFilter(filter2);
ResultScanner scanner2 = table.getScanner(scan);
for (Result res : scanner2) {
   System.out.println(res);
}
```